# Hide and Show Process from task manager

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Delphi 2010

I have a listbox which I fill with a list of all process IDs.

```
function EnumProcess(hHwnd: HWND;lParam : integer): boolean; stdcall;
var
  pPid : DWORD;
  title, className : string;
begin
  if(hHwnd=NULL) then
  begin
   result := false;
  end
  else
  begin
   GetWindowThreadProcessId(hHwnd,pPid);
   SetLength(className, 255);
   SetLength(className, GetClassName(hHwnd, PChar(className), Length(className)));
   SetLength(title, 255);
   SetLength(title, GetWindowText(hHwnd, PChar(title), Length(title)));
   //form1.ListBox1.Items.Add('Class Name = ' + className + '; Title = ' + title + '; HWND = ' + IntToStr(hHwnd) + '; Pid = ' + IntToStr(pPid));
   form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(pPid));
   result := true;
  end;
end;
```

Is there a way to hide and show a PID? I need a function to Hide and a function to show or one that can handle both

```
function HidePID(Value: DWord): Boolean;

function ShowPID(Value: DWord): Boolean;
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to hide the PID from your list. Or do you want to hide it from task manager like a rootkit would?

Comment: Hide it from task manager please (after selecting from list and clicking hide). Just curious if this is possible?

Comment: In which case, what relevance is the code in the question? Are you trying to write malware, a rootkit?

Comment: No, it is not for malicious purposes. But I have seen your anser below, and I expected as much. I will accept that - thanks

Comment: FWIW, whether or not you regard it as malicious, all anti-malware software will regard anything that attempts to hide the existence of a process as being malware.

Comment: It highly depends on if you mean to hide the *process* or the *application* - those are two different things in the Task Manager. Refer to the answer below from Ian Boyd.

Comment: @Jerry talk of PID suggests process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no supported way to hide a process from the system task manager.

Answer (score 2):

Task Manager shows you *"applications"* that are running.

For example right now my desktop only five *"applications"*, and only those 5 appear in **Task Manager**:

[image]

Task Manager does not show you *"background applications"*, *"services"*, or applications being run by other others. For example, right now my logged in session is also running:

- uTorrent
- Steam
- Process Explorer
- Skype
- Skydrive
- Action Outline

The reason you don't see those programs in **Task Manager** is because there is no visible **window** associated with those applications. And there is your answer:

> To hide your application from **Task Manager**: do not show any visible window.

**Note**: You can't hide your *process*; to do so would violate the [*"Arms race between programs and users"*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx)

Comment: Has Windows changed a lot since Windows XP in this respect?  As far as I'm aware (using XP's Task Manager), you can't disappear an app from the "Processes" tab, but you CAN disappear an app very easily from the "Applications" tab by explicitly setting Application.Title to '' in the dpr.  Of course, if this is a systray app, hiding the taskbar entry would be smart too.  Is this not the case anymore in newer versions?

Comment: You still cannot disappear an app from the processes tab.

Comment: Yes, this applies only for the *applications* which are running, but it does not apply to the *processes* which are running. Two different stories.